# convert unix time to w3 time in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp, data-conversion

the database has fields stored in unix time, ie. 1328202426

and I have an api call of an open source standard that takes w3 time, ie. 2010-01-01T00:00:00Z

a) convert w3 time, to the unix time

b) convert the unix time back to w3 time

in PHP

how would this be done? does anyone have some resources for this or will we be inventing the wheel

i did look at some date conversion function that comes with php

Comment: have you tried the PHP Manual http://php.net/date? or [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=convert+unix+time+to+w3+time+in+php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a.) convert w3 time, to the unix time

```
$date = "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z";
strtotime($date);
```

b.) convert the unix time back to w3 time

```
date(DATE_W3C, $timestamp);
```

Comment: PHP defines two constants for that date format, `DateTime::W3C` and `DATE_W3C`, so you don't need to specify that manually.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks! Didn't knew that. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Mogria: Check the wording of your answer, I have the feeling it is the other way round. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

seeing as this is coming from the database I'm assuming mysql here there are functions that can manipulate a timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME converts to a format that you can specify. Either that or use the php date function.

Have a look on this page 
[mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)